# What is the best encryption library in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, encryption

What is the best encryption library in C/C++ In terms of:

- entropy
- quality
- ease of use
- readability
- portability
- performance

What's your favorite and why do you like it?

Comment: I think for questions like this you should specify if your project is in C or C++. Technically you can use a C library in a C++ project obviously, but I see that as a last resort.

Comment: Really strange that no one mentioned the really good Botan library ( http://botan.randombit.net/ ).

Answer (score 27):

We've used [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) with good success. Portable, standards compliant and easy to use.

Comment: Given the current revelations about the state of development, and organization of the OpenSSL library I think this library should probably be avoided for a bit.  On the other hand there are a lot of organizations now involved in improving it, so I expect it to be quite good in the near future.

Comment: @JoshuaKolden could you elaborate? Why do you think it should be avoided, and do you think anything changed in the past year?

Comment: @rr At the time (a year ago), it was a revelation that OpenSSL had not been nearly as well reviewed as people had assumed, presumably merely by the fact of it being open source.  Now with the various security issues that have been discovered it seems to be under more focused scrutiny, and so has received the benefit of that  scrutiny.  Because of this, I'd suspect OpenSSL is now quite good, and getting better.

Answer (score 14):

I've used CryptoPP in the past (http://www.cryptopp.com/) and although its API style and programming paradigms take a little getting used to, I liked it in the end. It provides a wide range of symmetric and asymmetric algorithms with much flexibility. Documentation is so-so, the API docs are there but there's little 'high-level' overview and simple sample code. I ended up puzzling together pieces of code from around the net. It was easy to integrate into my project (linked statically). I'm using MSVC - 2003 when I started using it, now switched to 2008. It's portable across several platforms (check out the website). I've always used the default RNG, don't know which one that is.

Answer (score 11):

I'm gonna have to go with [LibTomCrypt](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt).  It's often overlooked for OpenSSL, but TomCrypt is just so lightweight and simple.  As for quality, TomCrypt is widely accepted as top-quality encryption.  Also, it's license is public domain which avoids the attribution hassle for your documentation that BSD licenses give you when writing commercial software.

Comment: What is the current development status for LibTomCrypt? This is my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264060/libtomcrypt-and-libtommathdevelopment-status

Comment: @bumhacks: I'd stay very far away from this library - its not maintained anymore, the author seems to have dropped off the face of the earth.

Comment: Note: It has moved to GitHub - https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt

Comment: From a quick look at the guide, this looks easy to use, as he use simple functions that return key, encryption, decryption ...

Answer (score 6):

[Crypto++](https://cryptopp.com) seems to have a very good reputation

Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto%2B%2B

GitHub - https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp

Comment: Can I use this library  for commercial use freely?

Comment: @george - it's under the Boost license: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto%2B%2B

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.I have seen the Boost License but can't understand it properly.Say I have one commercial application which makes use of crypto++ api after having built crypto++ in my PC.In such case, am I suppose to add any license or release my code since I made use of crypto++?

Comment: @george - IANAL .. but it seems you only have to provide the underlying libraries (or links thereunto), and *not* whatever you wrote that *uses* them. But you should check with either Boost, or an IP lawyer to verify (Boost license - https://www.boost.org/users/license.html)

Answer (score 5):

My favorite is GNU's library:

[libgcrypt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcrypt/)

Its performance is good, and it's used EVERYWHERE so it's very well tested.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, libgcrypt is LGPL licensed.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how is this different from GnuPG or GnuPGME from their documentation. What do they really mean by "separate module"?

Answer (score 3):

The C++ version isn't out yet but goolge KeyCzar http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/ might be worth looking at.  Whatever you feel about their business they do have a lot of smart programmers working for them.

Comment: The C++ version is out now.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start as it has JAVA library I can plug to Android.

Comment: It looks like the Javax crypto (and the C++ ) are based on openSSL.

Comment: Keyczar is deprecated. The Keyczar developers recommend [Tink](https://github.com/google/tink).

Answer (score 1):

[GPGme](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/index.en.html). Simple to use and compatible with the [OpenPGP format](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt)