# LibTomCrypt and LibTomMath—development status?

Tags: c, encryption

[LibTomCrypt](http://libtomcrypt.com/index.old.html) in the past has seemed like a very viable and useful option for encryption. And the associated [LibTomMath](http://math.libtomcrypt.com/) could be a useful math library. But lately, I can't see any development on it and it's ambiguous as to what is the "current" web site for it. E.g.:

- http://libtomcrypt.com/

  - which points to http://libtom.org/
  - [old page](http://libtomcrypt.com/index.old.html)
- http://libtomcrypt.org/ (now looks like it's been taken over by a domain squatter)

  - [in the past (Wayback Machine)](http://web.archive.org/web/20061205060439/http://libtomcrypt.org/)

What's the status, and is there a future for LibTomCrypt?

Comment: @Crog: I think he wrote a book, tried to make some money, it didn't work out, so like the rest of us went back to real work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It moved to github: https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt

Comment: Good to see LibTomCrypt being maintained. I was using it a while back and found it extremely easy to use.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, the author has dropped development of both libraries; any volunteer is free to pick the code up, and maintain it. Apparently this has not occurred (yet).

See for instance [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.crypt/msg/13411d479b29f451) (published in newsgroup sci.crypt) from the author of those libraries.