# Please suggest a good encryption library for VC++ 2008

Tags: c++, encryption

I am working on a small project and need your help. Here are the details:

- My project is in VC++ 2008
- I need to store some critical resource files bundles with my project exe in encrypted form
- While running the exe, I want to decrypt and use these files on the fly (without storing decrypted files in temp location)
- The files in question are binary files
- Project is small and simple
- Encryption can be simple or moderately secure

**I am looking for a encryption library/sdk/toolkit** for a simple project, the library should have following requirements

- It should be small and simple to work with, I dont need lots of features and I am short on development time
- It should be free to use
- It should be able to decrypt streams, or decrypt files directly in memory without storing them in any temp location
- It should have good tutorials/examples/community support, I am short on development time
- It should support more than one encryption strategies so that I should be able to switch to a better algorithm if needed, without changing library

I am really new to encryption libraries, kindly give your suggestion and I'll do background research on my own.

### Edit

Also, can you suggest a good way to hide my key inside an EXE? This is an click-and-run application without any registration or installation.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180870/what-is-the-best-encryption-library-in-c-cHa

Comment: "# Project is small and simple
# Encryption can be simple or moderately secure" Looks like you don't really need such a library then ...

Comment: Decrypting binary files vs ascii files is not very different, since you can just base64 encode/decode pretty easily if binary is not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will decrypt key be hardcoded in your program, or supplied from eg. a license file?

If hardcoded, don't bother looking for any type of fancy encryption, all you can hope for is a (very thin!) layer of obfuscation - even a simple XOR scrambling would be no worse than AES.

That said, check out [TomCrypt](http://libtom.org/?page=features&whatfile=crypt) or [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/).

### EDIT

You could also opt for something really simple such as [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm). Or you could stick with simple XOR encryption and compress your executable; a nice property of single-byte XOR encryption is that the encrypted data will still be compressible :) (caveat emptor: exe compression sometimes triggers false positives in antivirus apps).

The thing to keep in mind is that "if it runs, it can be broken", so focus on diverting casual prying eyes and forget about securing against "really interested people" - it takes a **lot** of effort and knowledge to do anything remotely successful.

### EDIT 2

For "hiding" the decryption key, you can simply store the binary key (what the decryption algorithm itself uses) rather than a textual representation - or you could use a string of gibberish. Doesn't matter much, casual users won't be able to use the key anyway, and you can't hide it from determined people :)

Comment: Yep encryption keys will be embedded in EXE, is there a better way to distribute keys?

Comment: That depends a lot on what you're doing; if there's no registration/license/whatever data required to run the app, and you simply want to keep prying eyes out, then I'd personally go for something simple.

Comment: What you said is correct, right now I just need to keep my data out of prying eyes, but I would need to update it to a better system in future. Also, something like "AES Encrypted" looks cool (if implemented properly) :)

Comment: If you move to a "content unlocked based on license" model at some point, you have a bunch of options... but do memorize the "if it runs, it will be broken" mantra :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading on this topic for the whole day and now its very clear to me that if a person is skilled enough to break XOR encryption, he can break the higher ones anyways. So I'll save energy and go with XOR or TEA!

Comment: Just to add in case anyone is reading here like me years later: THERE IS A HUGE DIFFERENCE.  The fact that if you use RSA public/private encoding, then someone can hack your program but they will never be able to create a keygenerator. And this gives more opportunities.

Comment: "never" depend on the keysize you choose, how you seed your PRNG, and the computing power your adversary has available. Various forms of RSA schemes *have* been broken because of implementation issues :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it really satisfies all of your requirements, but take a look at [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I have used Crypto++ and while I recognize the genius behind its conception... I loathe the fact that it takes a genius to use it (or close enough). There are good examples, but the slightest attempt to deviate from them turns into an extremely frustrating time.

I would recommend Google Keyczar: it's been designed for **easy** crypto:

- safe defaults, so don't worry about them
- multiple algorithms supported: asymmetric and symmetric, hashing
- handling of keys, with rotation mechanism etc... though that may not be extremely useful in your case

Check out the website: [Keyczar](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/)

Small note: there might be some issues with stream-decoding due to the API, I am not experienced enough with it to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an "UnAnswer": I know only one free library supporting the feature you need and this is not small or simple to work with. But anyway, have a look at [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com).
I guess others will also mention it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [Capicom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPICOM) ActiveX control.  It's  been discontinued, but I don't think that will cause you any issues.  It's a wrapper around Microsoft's CryptoAPI.

- It is just a wrapper around OS
  functions, so it's pretty small and
  easy to use.
- Microsoft does offer a redist for it,
  so you will be able to include it in
  your programs.
- It can decrypt strings.  Not sure
  about streams.
- It's from MS, so tutorials and
  community support is a given.
- It supports multiple encryption
  algorithms.  Note that some of the
  newer algorithms ones are not
  available on older versions of
  Windows, since it uses CryptoAPI.

It's not perfect, but if you want something you can develop quickly, it's not a bad choice.

Comment: Hey thats coll, i'll check it out right away. Is there any other crypto API which comes with windows/vs2008?

Comment: NVM, i just checked out "CAPICOM Alternatives" on MSDN and the list itself looks encrypted :\

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using Windows, I'd recommend the Windows Crypto API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388162(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: This takes a crypto professional to use.